# Trying to open the Google App Engine Shell with MobaXterm

Tags: google-app-engine, mobaxterm

I have a configuration running via Google App Engine. Google gives me the option on the website to open a cloud shell.

How can I open that shell on MobaXterm? There is no IP address or ssh that I can find on google.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gcloud cloud-shell ssh`.

You can open a local terminal in MobaXterm and execute that command. Keep in mind you should have authenticated before using `gcloud init` or the way you may want to authenticate. You can check this [article](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/accessing-cloud-shell-with-gcloud) for more info about this approach and [here's](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/cloud-shell) the details about the command.